# Passing cmdline arguments that have quotes in them

Tags: ruby, windows

I'm trying to create a ruby script that will run the following command:

```
UV4.exe -j0 -cr test.uvprojx -t"test"
```

I've tried to use Open3.capture3 as:

```
Open3.capture3("UV4.exe", '-j0', '-cr', 'test.uvprojx', '-t"test"')
```

The problem I am experiencing is that the last argument becomes

```
"-t\"test\""
```

which leads to an error for UV4 (Keil uVision IDE). If I try and escape the quotes I get

```
"-t\\\"test\\\""
```

which is also obviously wrong.

How can I get the last argument correct?

Comment: Try: `UV4.exe "-j0 -cr test.uvprojx -t\"test\""`

Comment: That still adds backslashes to the argument passed to the program the i.e. -`t\"tests\"`. I need it to be without the backslashes.

Comment: How about: `UV4.exe -j0 -cr test.uvprojx -t""test""` or `UV4.exe "-j0 -cr test.uvprojx -t"test""`

Comment: Have you tried `Open3.capture3('UV4.exe', '-j0', '-cr', 'test.uvprojx', '-ttest')`?

Comment: @Stefan `-ttest` won't add the quotes. I need it to pass `-t"test"`. But it keeps on escaping the quotes resulting in `-t\"test\"`.

Comment: @AndreKampling Sorry, not quite sure how you want me to enter that into Open3.capture, but it always adds a backslash. `-t""test""` becomes `-t\"\"test\"\"`

Comment: What happens if you omit the quotes? Is `-t"test"` any different from `-ttest`?

Comment: @Stefan Actually, it seems that the program does accept it. Yay! Thanks! Addresses my need, but I'd still like to know if there is a way to pass the quotes.

Comment: What about `Open3.capture3("UV4.exe", '-j0', '-cr', 'test.uvprojx', '-t', 'test')`?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR – use `'-ttest'` instead of `'-t"test"'` in Ruby.

---

If you type

```
$ cmd -t"foo"
```

at the command line, the quotes are not being passed to `cmd`. Instead, `cmd` receives a single argument `-tfoo`. It's equivalent to:

```
$ cmd -tfoo
```

But if you type:

```
$ cmd -tfoo bar
```

then `cmd` receives *two* arguments: `-tfoo` and `bar` because of the space in-between.

To avoid that, you have to *escape* the space somehow. All of these (and many more) would work:

```
$ cmd -tfoo\ bar
$ cmd -t"foo bar"
$ cmd "-tfoo bar"
```

With any of the above, `cmd` receives a single argument `-tfoo bar`.

In Ruby on the other hand, `capture3` will handle this for you, so no quotes are needed. You simply pass the command line arguments as separate method arguments:

```
Open3.capture3('cmd', '-tfoo bar')     #  $ cmd -tfoo bar
Open3.capture3('cmd', '-tfoo', 'bar')  #  $ cmd -tfoo\ bar
```

If you add `"` Ruby assumes that you want to pass that character *literally*:

```
Open3.capture3('cmd', '-t"foo bar"')
```

is equivalent to:

```
$ cmd -t'"foo bar"'
```

`cmd` receives a single argument `-t"foo bar"`, including the quotation characters.

Comment: `Open3.capture3('cmd', '-t"foo bar"')` results in `$cmd "-t\"foo bar\""`

Comment: @Flip that's equivalent to `$ cmd -t'"foo bar"'`, there are many ways to escape characters.

Comment: @Flip ... the important point is that the commands entered at the command line are interpreted (hence "command-line interpreter"). If you enter `cmd *.txt` then `cmd` does not receive `*.txt`, but the actual file names, e.g. `a.txt`, `b.txt`, `c.txt`.

Comment: Ah. I think I understand why it did not matter that much that when I did not used the quotes. Though it does make a difference in that Win10 cmd passes `\"foo bar\"` as is, i.e. with backslashes, and not as `"foo bar"`. So if I had spaces I would probably be pulling out my hair by now.

Comment: @Flip I see, maybe Windows is different in that regard. All *nix shells I have used so far would pass `"foo bar"` as `foo bar` and `\"foo bar\"` as `"foo bar"`.

Comment: I was thinking that it may have been related to the difference between the two. Perhaps the windows version of Open3 has not taken this in to account?

Comment: @Stefan, for the record, the Windows command line doesn't do globbing.  It is the application's responsibility to convert `*.txt` into a list of matching files, if it wishes to do so.